# Website Not Resizing Correctly on iPhone Portrait

Tags: css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, safari

I've looked at other questions posted on this site but something is not right. My website is only filling about 60% on iPhone 5/6 portrait view in Safari. I'm using Bootstrap 3. The page is http://www.freshbaby.com/v30/index.html

It resizes fine on Android Chrome as well as all major desktop browsers.

Here are the full contents in `<head>`

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <title>Freshbaby</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Could you put your code into a small, reproducable example on something like bootply.com or jsfiddle.net, that way folks like me who are on work computers don't have to worry about where your link is sending us (I'm sure it's fine, but I still wouldn't follow it) and when people view this question in years time and you've changed your site there will still be the source code there. Create a reproducible example might also help you fix the problem as well (happened to me before!)