# HTML pages not resizing on iPhone/iPad in portrait

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I'm no pro web developer, and I have a similar issue to the below, in that a few of my pages are not shrinking to fit the viewport of mobile devices in portrait. Landscape seems to be fine.

[Website Not Resizing Correctly on iPhone Portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146871/website-not-resizing-correctly-on-iphone-portrait)

I did have the site working previously, using the viewport metatag, but since the iOS update, it all reverted to actual web size. I removed the metatags based on this advice (it's not a responsive website)

http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho

Some pages work properly, and some do not. It makes no sense! The CSS is the same on all pages, yet they display differently, 'IMAGES', 'HOW IT WORKS' and 'PRICING' all behave properly. The other pages bleed outside of the viewport. Any ideas?

Thanks!

http://funandson.com

Here is the HTML for the bad page:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="webfonts/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css">
<link href="source/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<meta name="description" content="FUN & SON - bespoke photography for kids" />

<title>
FUN & SON - bespoke photography for kids
</title>


</head>



<body bgcolor="#d0d0d0">

<div id="container1">

<div class="image">
<img src="images/header.png" width="1200px" height="144px" name="background"/>
<h1>
<a href="aboutus2.html">ABOUT US</a>
<br />
<a href="images.html">IMAGES</a>
<br />
<a href="howitworks.html">HOW IT WORKS</a>
<br />
<a href="pricing.html">PRICING & PRODUCTS</a>
<br />
<a href="https://funandson2016.wordpress.com/">BLOG</a>
<br />
<a href="press.html">PRESS</a>
<br />
<a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/funandson/"><img src="images/insta.png" width="50px" height="50px" name="dot"/></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/Fun-Son-Bespoke-Photographic-Service-for-Kids-354285164695429/?ref=hl"><img src="images/fb.png" width="50px" height="50px" name="dot"/></a>
</h1>

<div id="copycontainer">



<h3>
<p style="margin-left: 60px; margin-top: 75px">
Coming soon
</p>
</h3>


<br />
<br />

</div>

</div>

</body>
```

The CSS is pretty standard too:

```
#container {
width:1200px;

}

#container1 {
width:1200px;

}

#container2 {
width: 770px;
float:left;
margin-top:95px;
margin-left:432px;
}

#copycontainer {
width: 800px;
height: auto;
float:left;
margin-top:70px;
margin-left:360px;
}


.cover a:hover {
text-shadow: 2px 2px: #ffffff;
} 

.images {
float: left;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
}

.image { 
margin:auto;
position: relative; 
width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */

}

.placeholder {
background-color: #FF0;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
padding-top: 0px;
float:left;
}

h1 { 
font-family: CeraStencilPRO-Light; 
font-weight: normal; 
font-style: normal; 
color: #7e7e7e; 
font-size:  22px;
line-height:40px; 
position: absolute; 
top: 185px; 
left: 0;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 60px; 
width: 100%; 
z-index:-20000;
}

h2 {
font-family: CeraStencilPRO-regular; 
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; 
color: #7e7e7e; 
font-size:  20px;
margin-top: 35px;

}   


h3 {
font-family: Helvetica; 
font-weight: normal; 
font-style: normal; 
color: #7e7e7e; 
font-size:  16px;
margin-top: 35px;
line-height: 21px;
}

h4 { 
font-family: CeraStencilPRO-Light; 
font-weight: normal; 
font-style: normal; 
color: #7e7e7e; 
font-size:  22px;
line-height:40px; 
position: absolute; 
top: 185px; 
left: 0;
margin-top: 60px; 
margin-left: 20px; 
width: 100%; 
}

h5 {
font-family: Helvetica; 
font-weight: normal; 
font-style: normal; 
color: #7e7e7e; 
font-size:  19px;
line-height: 21px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use bootstrap for responsive webdesign. It's easy to learn and you can rapidly create responsive html pages.

After including bootstrap insert this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">` and wrap the content of your html page in the bootstrap grid system.

Beginner Tutorial on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp).

Comment: Thanks and I totally agree. Anything I do in the future needs to be responsive. In this instance however my friend just wants a costless fix, so do you think there is a reason for this anomaly?

Comment: There is actually no hotfix, such that the html is responsive on all devices without using a grid system. You actually just need the grid system from bootstrap, this doesn't take much time. A other option would be W3.CSS if you don't want to use bootstrap.

Comment: You should close this question, when this answer is sufficient.

Comment: This answer is not sufficient as it does not provide a solution to the problem posed in the question.